# How do I create a data space in Data Cloud?

Tags: salesforce-cdp, datacloud, cdp

When I look at Data Space tab, I don't see a New button.

When I try to follow a default link to create a new record, /0vh/e in Classic or lightning/o/DataSpace/new?count=1 I don't see any inputs to enter name [image]
and if I click save, I can see an error `Required fields are missing: [Name]`.

Can I even create a data space or is this not available in trial Data Cloud org?

Answer (score 0):

There is a special process to create a data space, unlike other standard objects.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.c360_a_create_a_data_space.htm&type=5

> Go to Data Cloud Setup. Under Data Management, click Data Spaces.
> Click New, and give the data space a unique name that identifies its
> brand, region, or department. Enter the data space prefix, starting
> with a letter and including up to three alphanumeric characters.
> After you save the data space, you can’t change its prefix because
> it becomes part of the API name used to differentiate objects that
> exist in multiple data spaces. For example, the Individual DMO is in
> two data spaces: data space 1 with prefix DS1, and data space 2 with
> prefix DS2. When the Individual DMO is mapped to the data spaces,
> the object API names are DS1_Individual_dlm and DS2_Individual_dlm.
>
> ```
> Add an optional description about the purpose of the data space.
> Click Save.
> ```